# DataFrame.set_index() duplicates rows

Tags: python, pandas

I've been fighting this all day. After a lot of debugging, I understand that a `set_index()` call in my pandas DataFrame is the responsible for the

```
FutureWarning: reindexing with a non-unique Index is deprecated and will raise in a future version.
```

warning I've been getting. I have always used `set_index()` and don't understand how this could be creating duplicates. This is my debugging process (ugly I know):

```
ims = xml_to_df(os.environ["CUMULUS_XML"])
print(ims.duplicated(subset="Record Name").value_counts())

ims = format_data(ims)
print(ims.duplicated(subset="Document ID").value_counts())

ims.set_index("Document ID", inplace=True)
print(ims.duplicated().value_counts())
print(pd.DataFrame(ims.index.duplicated()).value_counts())
```

This is the output:

```
False    3996
True        1
dtype: int64

False    3996
True        1
dtype: int64

False    3608
True      389
dtype: int64

False    3996
True        1
dtype: int64
```

How can this be? (Record Name gets renamed to Document ID in `format_data`, hence the different subsets I'm testing for). Note that in the final DF the amount of duplicated rows is greater than that of duplicated indexes.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding, or is the problem just that you're setting an index on a column with duplicate entries?

Comment: as you can see there's only 1 duplicate on the Document ID column before I set it as index, when the duplicate count jumps to 389

Comment: the final df `index` also has only one duplicated value, whereas the general duplicated count is 389. I don't understand how a df can have 389 duplicated rows with only 1 duplicated index...

Comment: Furthermore, inspecting both the `duplicated` boolean series and the actual df as CSVs, the `True` values in the series appear only once in the df... Example: There's only one `001AAN005138` row in the df even though the boolean series states `001AAN005138,True`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understood what's happening. `duplicated()` only checks column values, it doesn't care about the index. So I had lots of rows (389) that even though had an unique identifier, had equal values in all columns. The single duplicated identifier (the one `True` value in the first checkings) had different column values, so it would even survive a `drop_duplicates()` call. Once `Document ID` became the index, `duplicated()` started picking every row that had equal values, even though their indexes were different.